# Covering of a vector space over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

> Let $k$ be a finite field and $V$ a finite-dimensional vector space over $k$.
>
> Let $d$ be the dimension of $V$ and $q$ the cardinal of $k$.
>
> Construct $q+1$ hyperplanes $V_1,\ldots,V_{q+1}$ such that $V=\bigcup_{i=1}^{q+1}V_i$

I tried induction on $d$, to no avail.

There has been discussion about this topic ([here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/coveringnumbersv2.pdf)), but it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it suffices to do this for a vector-space of dimension $2$. You can then simply "blow up" each line to a hyperplane in a larger space.

For dimension two, check that $q+1$ is in fact equal to the number of hyperplanes, that is lines in this case.

Comment: I don't understand how it suffices to prove it for any 2-dimensional space. I get that you can split the $d$-dimensional space into a direct sum of $2$-dimensional spaces (when $d$ is even), then use the previous lemma and end up with $d(q+1)/2$ hyperplanes.

Comment: Let $e_1,e_2,e_3, \dots, e_n$ be a basis. Let $W_i$ be a hyperplane in $\langle e_1, e_2 \rangle$ so a $1$-dimensional subspace, then $V_i = \langle W_i \cup \{e_3, \dots, e_{n}\} \rangle$ is $n-1$ dimensional, a hyperplane in the full space. And if $\cup W_i = \langle e_1, e_2 \rangle$ then $\cup V_i$ is the full space.

Comment: I see, thanks for your further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It is useful in this case to consider the dual.  In the dual space, your collection of hyperplanes covering every vector corresponds to a set of $(q+1)$ $1$-dimensional subspaces such that each hyperplane contains at least one of these $1$-spaces. If we fix a $2$-dimensional subspace $\pi$, then $\pi$ contains $q+1$ $1$-dimensional subspaces, and every hyperplane meets $\pi$ in a $1$-dimensional subspace.

This shows that by taking all of the $1$-dimensional subspaces in a common plane, we have the desired property. Then we can replace each of these $1$-dimensional subspaces with its dual (through any mapping, sending them to the orthogonal complement under the dot product will work), and we obtain a set of $q+1$ hyperplanes covering all of the points of $V$.